# document.getElementById() does not work with puppeteer finding and id on a <path> element on SVG

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, puppeteer

Puppeteer cannot select an svg element I have created with d3.js

This is a snippet from inside an async function:

```
  const chromiumBrowser = await puppeteer.launch(BROWSER_CONFIG);
  const page = await chromiumBrowser.newPage();
  await page.goto(WIND_DISPLAY_CLIENT_URL);

  const result = await page.evaluate(x => {
    return Promise.resolve(document.getElementById('needle'));
  }, 7);
  const result2 = await page.evaluate(x => {
    return Promise.resolve(document.getElementById('needle'));
  }, 7);
  console.log('what is the result?');
  console.log(result);
  console.log(result2);
  console.log(result === result2);

  await delay(20000);

  const result3 = await page.evaluate(x => {
    return Promise.resolve(document.getElementById('needle'));
  }, 7);

  console.log('result 3 is after the timeout?');
  console.log(result3);

  await chromiumBrowser.close();
```

This is how the SVG renders in the DOM:

```
<path d="M5,0C3.333333333333333,-67.5,1.6666666666666667,-135,0,-135C- 
1.6666666666666667,-135,-3.333333333333333,0,-5,0C-3.333333333333333,0,-1.6666666666666667,5,0,5C1.6666666666666667,5,3.333333333333333,2.5,5,0" 
id="needle" transform="rotate(-180)"></path>
```

And this is the d3 code snippet that renders it:

```
this.updatedParentSvg = parentSvg
  .append('g')
  .data([lineData])
  .attr('class', 'pointer')
  .attr('id', 'pointer')
  .attr('transform', center);

const pointerLine = d3.line().curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);
this.needle = this.updatedParentSvg
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', pointerLine)
  .attr('id', 'needle')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + this.config.minAngle + ')');
```

If I select the parent DOM g element, I can run document.getElementById and get values back but not on the path element, which is where the problem is.

Comment: Are your `id` attributes definitely unique? Does puppeteer give an error message?

Comment: My ID is unique and puppeteer gives an undefined

Comment: But no errors, just nothing

Comment: Looking through the puppeteer GitHub, some people have had problems with accessing SVG elements. It might be worth filing an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to locate an element by ID with puppeteer, you can use the CSS selector method `waitForSelector(...)` and input the string `"*[id='some_id']"`. Many frameworks use CSS selectors under the hood when locating elements by ID. Hope this helps!